# How to choose specific file names in php code?

Tags: php, regex, file-upload, mime-types

```
$_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/gif"
```

There is a problem to choose not only image.gif but whatever name is, such as *.gif . And, if it is possible, can you share some regex expressions for all names and especially image extensions. Maybe, there is a regex expression for some kind of file like (image, text, etc.,) For example, I want to choose all images

```
 `$_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "all names and image extentions"`
```

,
or just try to choose all video files

```
`$_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "all names and video extentions"`
```

Can anyone explain this? perhaps I don't understand `$_FILE[file][type]` code

Comment: It's unclear to me how this is a security question, but it's also unclear to me what your actual question is.  Are you trying to figure out what extension to use based on the mime type of the file?  Keep in mind that `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` is effectively user input and cannot be trusted.

Comment: @ConorMancone exactly, the code is wrapped in ' if() ' statement. I need to check if the type equal to what I expect. Guess it is mime type in the right part of the equation, but dont really understand how it works. $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/gif". The question is more about, to what I can compare $_FILES['file']['type']. And if it cannot be trusted, can I do something else?

Comment: It sounds like your question is basically, "How do I securely process image uploads?".  Unfortunately, that's a very broad question and there are many details to consider - far more than just "how to determine what type of file it is".  Different file types have different considerations, and even knowing the file type doesn't help you because polygot files are a thing.  To get you started though, the `type` key contains the mime type of the file, as reported by the client, and the list of mime types is extensive and grows every day.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types